# sshfs-win adds executable permission for all newly created files

Tags: windows, sshfs

I mounted remote ssh file system to my Windows using [*sshfs-win*](https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win). But when I create files in Windows they are marked as executable in Linux.

```
$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 14 Mar 31 20:42 file.txt
```

Note `x` permissions.

How do I prevent *sshfs-win* setting executable bit on files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `create_file_umask` option to *sshfs-win*. It is kind of `umask` option but for newly created files (for directories you would use `create_dir_umask`, for both - `create_umask`). But I don't know how to pass *sshfs* options to *sshfs-win* when you mount using [`net use`](https://superuser.com/a/1489959/515320) command. So I mount file system directly using `sshfs.exe` command. I use the following batch file:

```
SETLOCAL

SET PATH=C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin;%PATH%
sshfs user@host:/ -p 22 S: -f -C -o idmap=user -o create_file_umask=111 -o dothidden
```

Some flags are not required: `-f` (run in foreground), `-C` (use compression) and `-o dothidden` (mark files which names start with `.` as hidden in Windows), but they are useful. Since you mount it not as a service but as ordinal process, the mount is available only for your user. When you kill this batch, the mount disappears.