# Windows can't find SSHFS

Tags: ssh, sftp, sshfs, network-drive, hpc

When mapping a network drive on Windows 10, after installing SSHFS-Win and WinFsp, I get the error message "Windows can't find ssfhs". Any idea why this is happening? Here is the steps that lead to that message

[image]

**Edit:** Following [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/winfsp/c/8RsLm_Ye-OQ), I am able to map SFTP as a drive on Windows via the command line, by doing

```
cd C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin
set CYGFUSE=WinFsp;
set PATH=C:\Program Files\SSHFS-Win\bin
sshfs.exe -f -o idmap=user USER@SERVER: y:
```

I wonder why I can't seem to do it the other way.

Comment: Are you able to ping the machine with a host name of *sshfs*? Is that host name defined in your hosts file or your dns server? You should edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound I am fairly new to HPC, so I am not sure whether I understand your question. I have been able to do this before, but after server maintenance, I can't. The only practical difference is that they have implemented a Multi Factor Authentication (MFA), and I am not too sure how that is reflected in mapping a network drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to ping the server? Your error indicates you cannot.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe not, but why is that the case? I am not understanding why before MFA implementation it worked, but not now. Please see the edit section added to the question for further details.

Comment: AT Ramhound,  he shouldn't be able to ping sshfs, it's not the host

Comment: @samwolfe  when i've used sshfs my host has had a key and not a user/pass, so i've done \\sshfs.k   https://superuser.com/questions/1723410/cant-get-sshfs-win-manager-to-connect-to-an-ssh-sftp-server   But if you don't have a key then that won't apply to you.  I guess it's unlikely that you are using a key but if you were then try `sshfs.k` instead of `sshfs`, but otherwise stick to `sshfs`.   Do you have another computer you can try to `sshfs` to? or another computer with sshfs on it that you can try from?

Comment: AT Ramhound  see https://superuser.com/questions/1423371/sshfs-remote-directory-mounting-syntax  it's `\\prefix\user@host`  (host can be  IP or hostname).  So sshfs would be a prefix not a host

Comment: You installed winfsp which i'd ave thought would be the thing that gets `\\sshfs\...` to work..    If there was a public ssh server with a difficult user/pass that we could both connect to then we could test to see if eg I can connect and you can't.  It's not entirely clear what you are entering eg I see a plus symbol  in your screenshot https://i.imgur.com/fKImHWR.png  what are you up to there?! It should be `\\sshfs\user@host`  or for me cos I use a key  `\\sshfs.k\user@host`

Comment: @barlop The `+` symbol refers to a token user access to my Wi-Fi (eduroam). It's something like `user+worklaptop`, for example. I have no idea why this is asking me for this password, as previously that did not appear (before the HPC maintenance I mentioned in an earlier comment, which integrated MFA).

Comment: @barlop - Then I completely am confused by the error that indicates the host isn't available error message.

Comment: @samwolfe you could try setting up a VPS eg a digitalocean droplet , that you can SSH to, you can experiment with password or with key. And you can try to SSHFS to that... I might be able to set one up for you to try connecting to

Comment: @samwolfe see https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh72k.png  see how I used `net use` to connect to that SSH server.  (the output of net use is a bit ugly, I don't know if it should be like that ), but you can try SSHing to that computer I just set up.  And if I try `\\sshfs\root@....`  from the start menu then I get a weird error about permission.. but try it anyhow   The net use worked for me re the system there that you can try. Or you can set up your own on digitalocean and test. I'll leave that system up for a day or two incase you want to try it